# Node.js: How to select and join tables in node-orm?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, node-orm2

I have 2 tables in my mysql database `Owners` and `Pets`. I'm using node.js and [node-orm](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) to access the database. I would like to select the owners who own a brown pet and I don't know how to do it.

This is what I have tried with no luck:

```
// Require Dependencies
var mysql = require('mysql')
var orm = require('orm')

// Connect to Database
orm.connect("mysql://root:@localhost/example", function (err, database) {
    // Define Owner Model
    var Owner = database.define('owner', {
        name: String
    })

    // Define Pet Model
    var Pet = database.define('pets', {
        name: String,
        color: String,
    })

    // Create Association between Pets and Owners
    Pet.hasOne('owner', Owner, { reverse: 'pets' })

    // Select Owners who own a brown Pet
    Owner.find({ 
        pets: { 
            color: 'brown' 
        } 
     }, function(error, owners){
        if(error) throw error
        console.log(owners)
    })
})
```

The `pets` table/column is there because there is no error (it gives me an error if I use an non-existent column name), however it has no effect on the query at all. Is this possible with `node-orm`? If not, which orm should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Owner.findByPets({ color: 'brown' })` based on https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2#hasone